# $\overline {\text {span}_{\mathbb {Q}}A}=\text {span}_{\mathbb {R}}B$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $(X,\|.\|)$ be a Banach space. Let $A$ and $B$ are subset of $X$ such that $B$ is countable set.

Show that :

$$
\overline {A}=B\Rightarrow  \overline {\text {span}_{\mathbb {Q}}A}=\text {span}_{\mathbb {R}}B
$$

An idea please.

Comment: Well if you want to show equality think about why $\supseteq$ should be true and why $\subseteq$ should be true. Also in general only $\supseteq$ should be true, unless you are using different definitions of span than I am.

Comment: Just to give a counterexample illustrating s.harp's comment; if $B$ consists of linearly independent elements (which is possible in any infinite dimensional Banach space) then $\operatorname{span}_\mathbb{R} B$ cannot be closed since if it were it would be a Banach space with a countably infinite Hamel basis which cannot exist. But clearly $\operatorname{span}_\mathbb{Q} A$ is closed so the two are not equal.

Comment: "...which cannot exist ".  Why ?